# Visualforce Error : Exception: Data type not supported: Address

Tags: visualforce, query

Here is my visualForce page Code.

===========Visualforce page============

```
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockSection id="pageSection" title="OutPut" collapsible="false">
<apex:pageblockTable value="{!lstQuery}" var="TableValue">
<apex:repeat value="{!lstSobjectField}" var="field">// this list contins feild names
 <apex:column value="{!TableValue[field]}"/>
</apex:repeat>
</apex:pageblockTable>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Here is my Controller Code.

===========controller for this code==========

```
ObjectName='Account';
map<String,Schema.SObjectType> mapForSObject= schema.getGlobalDescribe();
    System.debug('===mapForSObject Value==='+mapForSObject);
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult ResultOfObject=mapForSObject.get(ObjectName).getDescribe();
    System.debug('===ResultOfObject==='+ResultOfObject);
    map<String,Schema.SObjectField> mapForField= ResultOfObject.fields.getMap();
    System.debug('===mapForField value==='+mapForField);
    for(schema.SObjectField field:mapForField.values()){
        schema.DescribeFieldResult ResulOfFiled=field.getDescribe();
        system.debug('===ResulOfFiled==='+ResulOfFiled);
        lstSobjectField.add(ResulOfFiled.getName());
        system.debug('===lstSobjectField==='+lstSobjectField);
    }
QueryForOutput='SELECT Name,Phone FROM ' +ObjectName+ 'LIMIT 5';
lstQuery=Database.Query(QueryForOutput);
```

While executing this code I am getting ERROR like "**Exception: Data type not supported: Address .**"

Comment: Can you please tell the line number in which you get the exception?

Comment: actually it is not showing the line number ..it directly shows that  "Exception: Data type not supported: Address ".